# "Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL" OneDrive Request

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, office365api

*https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children*

My app was working properly until Friday but now I am getting "Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL" error ! What is going on?

Comment: There isn't a lot to go on here. What kind of app? What OAUTH flow? Is this for any user or just one user? What is the complete error message/JSON result?

Comment: Sure! https://login.microsoftonline.com/oauth2/authorize
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "5feaaab9-54b2-4103-98c2-3de5e07c23ca",
            "date": "2017-09-19T15:13:59"
        }
    }
}

Comment: Perhaps report the error here like this similar ticket that expired: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/1511

Comment: A user with a similar problem [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/11344#issuecomment-763286222) said "Figured it out. The access token is an app token, not a user token." Perhaps this is the issue?

Comment: Another person with a similar issue [here](https://find-error.com/questions/64513417/unable-to-retrieve-users-mysite-url-onedrive-explorer-javascript-problem) said "Problem is in the azure subscription, not in any of the accounts. I have created new subscription and all is fine. Seems that this use case or test cannot be done for free"

Comment: Here is another similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71517200/accessing-ms-graph-unable-to-retrieve-users-mysite-url-using-client-credenti/71563306#71563306

Answer (score 0):

your Office 365 subscription is in locked out state. I expect that it's not only Microsoft Graph calls that don't work, but OneDrive and other Office products can't be used directly either, without an active license.

Comment: I get the same error with a proper licence