# Accessing MS Graph 'Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL.' Using Client Credentials One Drive

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

'Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL.' Using Client Credentials One Drive

is this because I'm using 365 family? not 365 business ?

> {
> "error": {
> "code": "UnknownError",
> "message": "Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL.",
> "innerError": {
> "date": "2022-03-17T17:08:21",
> "request-id": "a6717666-1188-4e65-af8f-61e14e419d82",
> "client-request-id": "a6717666-1188-4e65-af8f-61e14e419d82"
> }
> }
> }

Comment: Are these helpful? [Microsoft Login problem](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/1388), [Getting Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL even if the drive exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51744228/getting-unable-to-retrieve-users-mysite-url-even-if-the-drive-exists), [Resolve Microsoft Graph authorization errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/resolve-auth-errors), and [Microsoft Graph request BadRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51334499/microsoft-graph-request-badrequest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked and confirmed with azure,

that only Microsoft Business Plan is allowed to directly communicate with client credentials on Azure,

if you are not Business

then Delegate Permission is only allowed.

Annoying but, it will do.

the Unknown return is currently, because the account I'm using doesn't currently have a license in azure for One Drive Business.

thus the returning the Unknown Error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).